# Remove bbcode size from post text

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

Forgive me for not being better at regular expressions.

**Apologies: example is updated**

I am cleaning up some garbage in a phpBB forum with a PHP script. phpBB encodes bbcode with some sort of key, an 8 digit string that appears after a colon.  Here is an example:

```
outer [size=5:24f81ld3]inner text[/size:24f81ld3] outer
```

I am trying to strip out where the size is one character, not two, so the above would become:

```
outer inner text outer
```

But this:

```
outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size:24f81ld3] outer
```

Would **NOT** become this:

```
outer inner text outer
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code

```
function remove_phpbb_garbage($str)
{
  return preg_replace('/\[size=[0-9a-z](?::[0-9a-z]+)?\]((?:[^\[]|\[(?!\/size))*)\[\/size(?::[0-9a-z]+)?\]/i', '\1', $str);
}
```

Here are the test use cases:

```
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("outer [size=1]inner text[/size] outer"), "\n";
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("outer [size=5:24f81ld3]inner text[/size] outer"), "\n";
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size] outer"), "\n";
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size] outer"), "\n";
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("outer [size=5:24f81ld3]inner text[/size:24f81ld3] outer"), "\n";
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size:24f81ld3] outer"), "\n";
echo remove_phpbb_garbage("[b:2q9o3yfx][size=2:2q9o3yfx][font=Arial:2q9o3yfx]Please be careful on how to Jail break your Iphone. In case if you are not already did it. There is a lot of specific instructions How to Jail break your phone on the web. Please read up before attempting a Jail break.[/font:2q9o3yfx][/size:2q9o3yfx][/b:2q9o3yfx] _________________ [bg2ads1:2q9o3yfx][/bg2ads1:2q9o3yfx]"), "\n";
```

Here's the output:

```
outer inner text outer
outer inner text outer
outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size] outer
outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size] outer
outer inner text outer
outer [size=100:24f81ld3]inner text[/size:24f81ld3] outer
[b:2q9o3yfx][font=Arial:2q9o3yfx]Please be careful on how to Jail break your Iphone. In case if you are not already did it. There is a lot of specific instructions How to Jail break your phone on the web. Please read up before attempting a Jail break.[/font:2q9o3yfx][/b:2q9o3yfx] _________________ [bg2ads1:2q9o3yfx][/bg2ads1:2q9o3yfx]
```

---

**Important note:** The function does *not* handle nested `size` tags correctly!

---

If you're interested in regular expressions, this wonderful resource covers them in all details and flavors: 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Would this handle situations where the size is only 1 character?

Comment: @Mark, I've updated the function to handle 1-char size (without trailing `:123xyz`). Please write what exactly does not work (input + expected output).

Comment: Sorry, still does not work. No substitutions are made.

Comment: Here is an example: [b:2q9o3yfx][size=2:2q9o3yfx][font=Arial:2q9o3yfx]Please be careful on how to Jail break your Iphone. In case if you are not already did it. There is a lot of specific instructions How to Jail break your phone on the web. Please read up before attempting a Jail break.[/font:2q9o3yfx][/size:2q9o3yfx][/b:2q9o3yfx] _________________ [bg2ads1:2q9o3yfx][/bg2ads1:2q9o3yfx]

Comment: Sorry about my incorrect example. The closing tag also had content after the colon, [/size:24f81ld3]

Comment: Awesome! I do have tags nested inside of other tags, but it's unlikely that two size tags are nested inside one another.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the size tag only if it's value is exactly one character.

Regex:

```
\[(size)=[^:]:([^\]\[]*)\]([^\[\]]*)\[\/\1:\2]
```

Replacement string:

```
$3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iP5rJ6/2)

Code would be,

```
preg_replace('~\[(size)=[^:]:([^\]\[]*)\]([^\[\]]*)\[\/\1:\2]~', '$3', $str);
```

Comment: return preg_replace('\[(size)=[^:]:[^\]\[]*\]([^\[\]]*)\[\/\1]', '$2', $str); gives this: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: you forget to add the php delimiters. See my update.

Comment: It seems to get the first instance of a match, not all matches. Is there a way to get all matches?